# Prolog: Sum one element of a list at a time

Tags: list, prolog, sum, iteration, swi-prolog

I'm new to Prolog and have decided to try to solve a problem in which I have a sequence of symbols that each have the value 1 or -1. What I need is to add them all together, one element at a time, and extract at which index the sum for the first time drops below 0. Since I'm coming from an imperative background, I'm imagining a count variable and a for-loop, but obviously I can't do that in Prolog.

```
value('(', 1).
value(')', -1).

main(R) :- readFile("input", R), ???

readFile(Path, R) :- 
    open(Path, read, File), 
    read_string(File, _, Str), 
    stringToCharList(Str, Xs), 
    maplist(value, Xs, R).

stringToCharList(String, Characters) :-
    name(String, Xs),
    maplist(toChar, Xs, Characters ).

toChar(X, Y) :- name(Y, [X]).
```

As you can see, all that I've really managed so far is to read the file that contains the sequence, and convert it to 1s and -1s. I have no idea where to go from here. I suppose the problem is three-fold:

- I need to iterate over a list
- I need to sum each element in the list
- I need to return a certain index

Any suggestions? Can I somehow cut off the list where iteration would have dropped the sum below zero, and just return the length?

Comment: What does your input file look like? If it's a valid Prolog term or terms, then Prolog I/O can just read them and you don't need to parse them.

Comment: Just a long string of parentheses.

Comment: Now that you have your list of 1's and -1's, just do a simple recursive predicate to walk through the list, accumulating the sum until you hit 0. The counter will be the index. `index_at_zero_sum(L, Index) :- index_at_zero_sum(L, 0, Index).` to get started. The 2nd argument is the initial sum which is, of course, `0`. Your `index_at_zero_sum/3` will be recursive and should terminate in a base case when the sum becomes 0 again. It will otherwise fail by default (it didn't achieve zero sum).

Comment: You could also do the summing on the fly as you read the file. You would just need to add the accumulator and a variable for the index to your existing predicate.

Comment: That makes sense. Although I'm not sure how to implement it. Should my /3 look something like this? 
`index_at_zero_sum([], 0, _). 
index_at_zero_sum([H|T], S, I) :- Sum is S+H, Index is I+1, index_at_zero_sum(T, Sum, Index).`

Comment: You just need to think about it logically. What does `index_at_zero_sum([], 0, _)` mean? `_` is usually a "don't care" variable. I suspect you actually do very much care. You probably need an aux variable for index, so that would mean 4 arguments to `index_at_zero_sum`. You start with a value of 0 for the aux index and increment it and keep passing the real index variable through without touching it. In your base case, you unify the aux index with the index since it is then the value you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use a principle in Prolog of an auxiliary variable to act as a counter until the conditions reach what we want. Then the auxiliary counter is unified with a variable at that point in the base case.

I'm assuming here, blindly, that your code works as stated. I did not test it (that's up to you).

```
main(IndexAtZeroSum) :- readFile("input", R), index_at_zero_sum(R, IndexAtZeroSum).

readFile(Path, R) :- 
    open(Path, read, File), 
    read_string(File, _, Str), 
    stringToCharList(Str, Xs), 
    maplist(value, Xs, R).

stringToCharList(String, Characters) :-
    name(String, Xs),
    maplist(toChar, Xs, Characters ).

toChar(X, Y) :- name(Y, [X]).

% The following predicate assumes indexing starting at 0
index_at_zero_sum([V|Vs], IndexAtZeroSum) :-
    index_at_zero_sum(Vs, V, 0, IndexAtZeroSum).

% When sum is zero, Index is what we want
index_at_zero_sum(_, 0, Index, Index).
index_at_zero_sum([V|Vs], Sum, CurIndex, Index) :-
    S is Sum + V,
    NextIndex is CurIndex + 1,
    index_at_zero_sum(Vs, S, NextIndex, Index).
```

`index_at_zero_sum/2` provides the index for the given list where the sum becomes zero. It does so by using an auxiliary predicate, `index_at_zero_sum/4`, starting with a sum at the first value (the sum being the value itself) and the current index starting at 0. So the 2nd argument is the sum at index 0. Subsequent calls to `index_at_zero_sum/4` increment the index and accumulate the sum until the sum becomes 0. At that point, the base case succeeds and unifies the 4th argument with the current index. If the sum never becomes 0 before the list becomes empty, the predicate fails.

---

You can also avoid reading the entire file and creating a numeric list by using `get_char/2`:

```
index_at_zero_sum(Path, Index) :-
    open(Path, read, File),
    get_char(File, C),
    value(C, V),
    (   index_at_zero_sum(File, V, 0, Index)
    ->  close(File)
    ;   close(File),
        fail
    ).

index_at_zero_sum(_, 0, Index, Index).
index_at_zero_sum(File, Sum, CurIndex, Index) :-
    get_char(File, C),
    value(C, V),
    S is Sum + V,
    NewIndex is CurIndex + 1,
    index_at_zero_sum(File, S, NewIndex, Index).
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Your tips in the comments got me on the right track, but I got stuck not figuring out how the break should be handled. Anyhow, this worked. :)